# Palette.Swatch - vibrant getTitleTextColor is not at all vibrant

Tags: android, palette

I am generating a palette from a bitmap. I am making sure that I am getting a valid vibrant swatch and setting text color to that swatch's [`getTitleTextColor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.Swatch.html#getTitleTextColor()). The docs say:

> Returns an appropriate color to use for any 'title' text which is displayed over this Swatch's color. **This color is guaranteed to have sufficient contrast.**

I after I get the text color, and set it I can hardly see the text.

### Code:

```
Palette.from(bmp).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                Palette.Swatch swatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
                if(swatch != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Vibrant swatch found");
                    tvTitle.setTextColor(swatch.getTitleTextColor());
                 } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No color swatch found");
                    tvTitle.setTextColor(palette.getDarkVibrantColor(defaultColor));
                }
            }
});
```

***Note:*** this is logging out "Vibrant swatch found"

### Results:

See the text in the bottom left of the image? Me either....

[image: ww]

Things worth noting:

- I have tried multiple bitmaps with the same results, just different shades of grey.
- TextView alpha is 100%.

### Edit:

[This is what I am trying to accomplish](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQscXNQY3dNdVlYeTQ/patterns-scrolling-techniques_flex_space_image_xhdpi_003.webm)

Comment: What's the alpha value of the TextView?

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy - 1.0. I also temporarily disables any themes that were affecting text views

Comment: It says sufficient contrast with the swatch's color, not contrast with the image - where are you setting the swatch's color as the background behind your text?

Comment: I am not setting the background of my text.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I guess I misunderstood. I thought the text color was enough as a standalone view over the bitmap.

Comment: @ianhanniballake See my edit. [This is what I am striving for](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQscXNQY3dNdVlYeTQ/patterns-scrolling-techniques_flex_space_image_xhdpi_003.webm)

Comment: You're supposed to use vibrant text color over vibrant background color - the color from which the text color is computed. Don't put it directly over the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this blog](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/20/palette-v21/):

> The different text colors roughly match up to the material design standard styles of the same name. The title text color will be more translucent as the text is larger and thus requires less color contrast. The body text color will be more opaque as text is smaller and thus requires more contrast from color.

So I think you should use `swatch.getBodyTextColor()` instead. Also note that this title / body text color has sufficient contrast with **the swatch's color** (`swatch.getRgb()`) which should be used as the background color for your text.